# NAvigationbar jumping when loading view

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, core-animation, uinavigationbar

I have implemented a container view controller (ios5) and now Im trying to implement custom animations/transitions for switching the view controllers.

But I have an issue when implementing any animation that involves a UINavigationController, the result is not as expected. For instance if I perform a flip from left animation when showing the controller with the navigation bar, the position for the navigation bar stays 44pxs below the original position and after the animation is performed the navigation bar will move smoothly to the original position which is really ugly...

This happens with every animation I perform, so I guess it has to be related only with the navigationcontroller.

This is the code I use for the flip transition

```
[self transitionFromViewController:fromViewController
                toViewController:toViewController
                        duration:1.0
                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                      animations:^{
                        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animation2" context:nil];
                        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
                        [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.7];
                        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:containerView cache:NO]; 
                        [UIView commitAnimations];
                      }
                      completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                        [toViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                        [fromViewController removeFromParentViewController];
                      }];
```

I also tried the following

```
[self transitionFromViewController:fromViewController
                toViewController:toViewController
                        duration:1.0
                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                      animations:^{
                      }
                      completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                        [toViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                        [fromViewController removeFromParentViewController];
                      }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the frame of navigation bar according iphone or ipad's and its orientation like this for portrait in iphone

```
 [self.navigationController.navigationBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 44)]; //for iphone  simarly for ipad and its orientation
```

You need to change your navigation bar frame to its actual position from status bar ie plus 20

Comment: I forgot to comment that the whole content is moved up, so If I set the navigation bar frame the content view will still move. I have tried to set both frames (navigation bar and content view) but only the navigation bar gets moved to the original position.

Comment: I just have checked the frame for the navigation bar and its correct in viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear (x = 0, y =0). Even that the navigation bar its moving from y = status bar height to y = 0... Strange...

Comment: Why? Its suppose that both NavigationController and navigation bar have a frame with a origin x=0 and y= 0, isn't it?

Comment: but as it gets changed so we change origin of y = 20

Comment: I dont understand what you mean. If I change the origin.y = 20 the bar will be placed at y=20, so yes, no jumping to the origin.y = 0 but then a space appears between the status bar and navigation bar.

Comment: change origin of y = 20 where its jumping upwards and again set y =0 where it doesnot jump.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem with `NavigationController` and `Container controller`. Actually it was the toolbar at the bottom of window. My solution is to hide the toolbar first, then show toolbar with animation after the main transition completed. It looks like part of the whole animation.

Here is how I hide and show toolbar:

```
[toNavController setToolbarHidden:YES];
[self transitionFromViewController:fromViewController
                toViewController:toNavController
                        duration:1.0
                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                      animations:^{
                      }
                      completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                        [toNavController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                        [fromViewController removeFromParentViewController];

                        [toNavController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];
                      }];
```

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidLoad set frame.origin.y to 1. You still have a jumping but with 1 pixel.